Does the derivative of function need to exist for a function to be differentiable?

Upon solving the differential eqn the solution you get is $ x^3-7x-6 = y$. My doubt is in option D. The derivative of the function according to the differential equation does not exist at $x=0$. So should one mark option D as correct or not because for Rolle's theorem to be applicable the function should be differentiable.

Why does the derivative at $x=0$ matter for $[-2,-1]$?

Being differentiable is having a derivative by definition. The problem is whether your function has derivative on the considered domain. Note that $0 \notin [-2,-1]$

@ioveri for rolle's theorem to be applicable f(-2) == f(-1). this will only be true for particular values of c(not all) since the diff eqn simply doesnt hold at 0 you could in theory have two independent branches.

@zynox then probably none of them are correct.

What course is this from?  Calculus I or II?
Or Differential Equations?

The function is explicitly an ODE solution. The solution for the IVP with initial point at $x=1$ can not cross the vertical axis $x=0$. On the negative half axis the solution either does not exist or is unspecified, the coefficient of the cubic term can be different.
(B) is either wrong, as either there is only one root on the positive half axis where there is a solution; or, if patched solutions are admissible as generalized concept, it is undecidable as the partial function on the negative half-axis is not specified.
Likewise (C) and (D) deal with information that is not tied down.

The question is evidently aimed at techiques to find the answers without solving it trivially by a polynomial. This is done simply by the homogenous part, yiedling $f_0 = c x^3 $ and a special solution can be determined by setting the right side to be  a constant, such that $x\to y(x)$ is linear in $x$.
So we know, in general, $y$ is a cubic with a linear term.
The questions get their answer by the two signs sign of the linear and cubic term and, finally, evaluating if the  two points of $f'=0$ are extrema.
Look for the zeros of the derivative
$$3 \frac{y}{x} +14 + \frac{18}{x}=0  \quad \longleftarrow \quad y=-\frac{2}{3} \left(7 x +9\right)$$
Is this point an extremum? Determine  the second derivative
$$\left(\partial_x \left(3\ \frac{f(x)}{x} +14+\frac{18}{x}\right) \quad \text{with} \quad  f'\to  0 , \quad f\to -\frac{2}{3} (7 x+9)\right) = \frac{14}{x}?$$
... and so on
